# Combine a bit field value over multiple rows (Logical OR accumulation)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

If I have a sql server database table with a bit flag column and I would like to aggregate a logical OR of all rows, or some rows based on a predicate how can I achieve this.

For example, an order detail table has a flag field with site1 = 1 and site2 = 2.

If an order has two order detail records containing a site1 and site 2 then I would expect a resultant value of 3 for the select.

Such logic might look something like this, but there is no aggregation function for logical OR (or is there).

```
select ORDERNUM, SUM(LOGICAL OR (Flag)) 
  FROM ORDER_DETAIL 
 GROUP BY ORDERNUM
```

Some examples:

```
site2
site2
site1
would equal 3

site2
site2
would equal 2

site1
would equal 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Distinct Sum`

```
select ORDERNUM, SUM(distinct LOGICAL) 
  FROM ORDER_DETAIL 
 GROUP BY ORDERNUM
```

Comment: Note that this solution only works if each row has a single bit value (which works for the example the user provided). But if we have data across rows like:  1, 1, 3, 7 (which you would want the result to be 7), you would get 11.